# .htaccess redirect specific IP address to specific folder

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

I need to redirect visitors with a specific IP address into a specific folder in the server.
For istance, a client with IP `123.123.123.123` should be redirected to `www.example.com/folder1/` and a client with IP `234.234.234.234` should be redirected to `www.example.com/folder2/`
How can I do that with `.htaccess` or with the `apache2.conf` file?

Answer (score 0):

```
RewriteEngine On    
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} !^111\.111\.111\111$
RewriteRule .* /folder1

RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} !^222\.222\.222\222$
RewriteRule .* /folder2
```

Comment: Usually it is a good idea to explain the code you post. This allows newer developers to understand what the code does.